# Dangers of pre-firing a propertyChangeEvent

Tags: java, swing, events

What are the dangers, if any, of firing a propertyChangeEvent before actually changing the property?

Currently I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
public void setConfidence (int newConfidence) {
    int old = confidence;
    confidence = newConfidence;
    pcs.firePropertyChange("confidence", old, confidence);
}
```

It would be prettier, and avoid a copy, to fire the event before changing the property:

```
public void setConfidence (int newConfidence) {
    pcs.firePropertyChange("confidence", confidence, newConfidence);
    confidence = newConfidence;
}
```

In a single-threaded application, are there any dangers in pre-firing the event? Or other reasons to prefer firing after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second bit of code, you're notifying listeners that the state has changed when it hasn't, which is not good or safe. What if the listeners have their own behavior or state change that depends on the new state being present at the time of notification? One of the main rules of using notification is that the notifying code should not need to have knowledge of what the listening code does with the information, and your second bit of code does not satisfy this. Stick with the first way.